# Internal inconsistency error (didStartTask)

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild, swift-package-manager

Sometimes, about 2 times out of 10, when I run my application through Xcode, I get this error:

```
Internal inconsistency error (didStartTask): targetID (174) not found in _activeTargets.
Internal inconsistency error (didEndTask): '12' missing from _activeTasks.
```

This error is reproduced using **Xcode 14.x, 15.x** versions.

This error can be fixed by cleaning up the project and rebuilding it.
I found thread on [forums.swift.org](https://forums.swift.org/t/internal-inconsistency-error-didstarttask/61194), but it has no solution.

Judging by the thread, the problem may be in SPM and incorrect connection of dependencies

Anyone have a solution?

Comment: do any of your swift packages use a `BuildToolPlugin`?

Comment: @markturnip Yes, I use several BuildToolPlugins. But plugin work successfully and the error occurred at the time of planning the build

Comment: Also getting this error in the `Xcode 15.1 Beta 3`, though here it actually breaks the build process with a `Build failed` and has a more detailed message: `Internal inconsistency error: received multiple target ended messages for target ID '1' or received target ended message but did not receive corresponding target started message, while retrieving parent activity in taskStarted message.` and `Internal inconsistency error: received multiple task ended messages for task ID '4' or received task ended message but did not receive corresponding task started message.`

Comment: I'm using a local SPM package with the `SwiftGenPlugin` `.plugin` as well

Comment: Still, the issue is on Xcode 15.0.1. I'm using `SwiftGenPlugin`.

Comment: The issue is still present on Xcode 15.2

Comment: Getting this on 15.3 with R.swift SPM plugin

Answer (score 3):

I am not at all sure if this will help, but I had a similar message today a bunch of times and found this question, then tried Product -> Clean Build Folder and that cleared it up for the rest of the day. Seems like it had to do with something I changed on an observable value and something didn't get rebuilt fully.